# Query failing for seemingly identical strings?

Tags: string, postgresql, character-encoding

I have the following two example queries:

```
select * from schema.test where id = 'Z6_SGIL_2115'
select * from schema.test where id = 'Z6_SGIL_2115'
```

The top query fails, the second one works. When the first query failed I copied & pasted the id value directly from the table into the query and it succeeded.

The strings *look* identical but obviously aren't.

What is the difference between the two? Is it possible one or more of the characters are encoded?

Comment: http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html Certainly makes it look like the two `id` strings are identical.  In what way is the first query failing?  Just not returning any rows?

Comment: I pasted them from here into a hex editor and they are exactly the same. Of course, something could have been lost between what you pasted in your post and what SO displays for me to copy. I'd suggest pasting them into a hex editor yourself to see the actual values.

Comment: What is the database encoding, and where are you running the query (in code, psql, pgadmin)?

Comment: @ZacharyCross It looks like the encoding _is_ lost in SO. After pasting the string directly from the query into the link provided, there _is_ an encoded character just after the first apostrophe in the working string:  `U+FEFF : ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE [ZWNBSP] (alias BYTE ORDER MARK [BOM])`

Comment: ooh, that's going to hurt.

Comment: You should write that as answer to your own question. It might help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unprintable data in the search patterns/strings can be detected with any hex editor or: http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html